# Getting session timeout value from WebSphere Application Server using Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, session-timeout, websphere-7

Is it possible to get session timeout value set in WebSphere Application Server from Java code dynamically?

I need to show an alert 5 minutes before the actual session expires. Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Since it's from server config, I had a thought that we may be able to get it using Java Code.Is it possible to detect all keypress events with javascript ? Considering that I know the session timeout in advance, I can run a timer manually and show the alert if the application is idle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the session timeout with the funcion  getMaxInactiveInterval().You can also get the timestamp of session creation using a Listener that stores that value on a Session scoped variable. If you query both values from the browser, you can activate a timer that solves your problem.

For the timeout: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html

For the listener (watch SessionLifeCycleEventExample): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm